# No overload for method 'Distance' takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to code adversaries to move between two points and destroy the player if touched.

```
public class MovementBetweenPoints : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform[] keyPoints;
    public float speed;
    private int currentKeyPoint;
    public float min_Distance;
    public float Distance;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        transform.position = keyPoints[0].position;
        currentKeyPoint = 1;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    { 
        // ----------- Error happens on next line
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position - keyPoints[currentKeyPoint].position) <= min_Distance)   
        {
            currentKeyPoint++;
        }

        if (currentKeyPoint >= keyPoints.Length)
        {
            currentKeyPoint = 0;
        }

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, keyPoints[currentKeyPoint].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Player)
    {
        Destroy(Player.gameObject);
    }

}
```

> No overload for method 'Distance' takes 1 arguments."

How to fix it?

Comment: What part of error message is confusing to you? It is very hard to provide *useful* help without that information.

Comment: In current state of the question it does not look like any different from thousands of similar once that could be found by searching for error message - (i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517794/how-to-fix-no-overload-for-method-takes-0-arguments I used as duplicate). If that does not provide enough explanation - make sure to edit your question to clarify what you don't understand (may need to ask new, more specific question for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Distance` call returns the distance between two points but the code you wrote only gives one point.  I think you have a "-" where you wanted a",".
Try this:

```
if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, keyPoints[currentKeyPoint].position) <= min_Distance)
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much for your help!